# Using Generic Type parameter in Angular material dialog dialog.open method

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular6

I am trying to write a generic service that will take Type and options as parameters and display material popup using material, but when I try to use generic parameter as parameter to open method typescript is showing following error
"'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here"

```
export class SharedMethodsService {
    constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

    displayPopup<T>(options) {
        this.dialog.open(T, options)
    }
}
```

Comment: There error is telling you what you've done wrong. `MatDialog.open()` requires a component or template (value), not just a type. So something like `displayPopup<T>(dialogComponent<T>, options) { this.dialog.open(dialogComponent, options); }`. See MatDialog.open source code: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/9eeb4b5aa0473c0815a73bfe3c2ed6164d86a3b3/src/material/dialog/dialog.ts#L128.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I've already fixed the issue yesterday

Comment: @SohelAhmed Would you mind updating the question with what you ended up doing to solve the issue? I am trying to do the same thing and not having much luck

Comment: displayPopup<T>(component: ComponentType<T> | TemplateRef<T>, options) {
        return this.dialog.open(component, options);
    }

Comment: @markrawlingson please copy the above and access it using a shared service